# what is equivalance for #pragma package(smart_init) in msvc?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++builder, msvc12

In ***embarcadero*** (Borland) C++ compiler we have following pragma Directive:

- `#pragma package(smart_init)`
- `#pragma package(smart_init, weak)`

as describe in [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Pragma_package).

- ***What are the pragma directives defined in msvc(Visual C++ compiler) equivalence for above feature?***

  For you convenience take a look at [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: "Packages" and "units" are quite specific to Embarcadero and its environments, due to its Delphi relationship. Try to write portable code which doesn't rely on specific initialization order between [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) (which are different from Delphi and Embarcadero "units").

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you. Is this have any relation/quite similar behavior with `init_seg` in msvc?

Comment: Did you try `#pagma init_seg` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977wcck.aspx)?

Comment: The VC++ `init_seg` pragma doesn't seem to have a fixed order of initialization between different libraries, there's no mention of "order of dependency" like the `#pragma package(smart_init)` have. You really should not build your design around specific implementations order of initialization.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude gottcha .. thanks